# Store Hibernate query results into Hashmap

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, hashmap

i want to store name and id of  HQL query result into a Hashmap . here is my code. is there any better way to do it?

```
    String hql = "FROM Student";
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    List queryResults = query.list();
    List<Student> result = new ArrayList<Student>();

    Iterator it = queryResults.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Student student = (Student) it.next();
        result.add(student);
    }
    Map mapresult = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,String>();

    for (Student Maprslt : result)
        mapresult.put(Maprslt.getId(), Maprslt.getName());
```

Answer (score 3):

You could put it all in a single `foreach` loop, which is designed to loop over an `Iterable` or array.

```
String hql = "FROM Student";
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
List queryResults = query.list();

Map<Integer,String> mapresult = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (Object obj : queryResults) {
    Student student = (Student) obj;
    mapresult.put(student.getId(), student.getName());
}
```